# Querying list of nested models with FireO in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using FireO to interact with Google Firestore in my Python application. I have a data model with nested lists, and I'm having trouble querying based on a condition within these nested lists.

Here are my relevant data models:

```
from fireo.fields import TextField, ListField
from fireo.models import Model, NestedModel


class InnerModel(Model):
    field1 = TextField()


class OuterModel(Model):
    another_field = NumberField()
    field2 = ListField(NestedModel(InnerModel))

    class Meta:
        collection_name = "outer_model"
```

What I am trying to do, is fetch all the `OuterModel` objects where at least one of the items `field1` in the list of `InnerModel` is equal to a value.

What I have tried but did not work was:

```
items = (
    OuterModel.collection
    .filter("field2.field1", "array_contains", "value")
    .get()
)
```

I am expecting documents that have this structure:

```
collection: outer_model

another_field: 123
field2:
   0:
       field1: value1
   1:
       field1: value2
   2:
       field1: **value**
```

Because list item at position 2 has the value we are looking for, I expect the whole object to be returned. Of course `InnerModel` has other fields as well, hence why I am using a `NestedModel`.

I am adding a screenshot of the desired document in the Firestore web interface:
[image]

How can I properly query based on conditions within a nested list in FireO?

I appreciate any insights or examples on how to achieve this. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show a screenshot from the Firestore console of a document you expect to be returned by this query?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I updated the question

Comment: Please show a *screenshot* from the Firestore web interface of the document.

Comment: @FrankVanPuffelen I did not understand in the first place, sorry. I posted the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array-contains` operator can only check whether an array contains a complete element. So for your top-level `field2`, you can use `array-contains` to determine if it contains `{ "extra_field": 123, "field1": "value1" }`.

Firestore has no operator to check for a partial match in an array though, which is what you're trying to do.

The common workaround is to create an additional field with just the parts of `field2` that you want to filter on. So with your (abstract) field-names, that'd be:

```
field1_values_infield2: ["value", "value1", "value2"]
```

And then:

```
.filter("field1_values_infield2", "array_contains", "value")
```

This practice of adding additional data to allow for a use-case is quite common in NoSQL databases, and is commonly referred to as denormalization. If you're new to this, I recommend checking out the excellent video series [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).

Comment: This is really helpful and the way to go. Thank you